# How to resolve "Component 'FLASH.OCX' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid" on downloaded program

Tags: flash

I have been getting this error now on a program I downloaded a while back. All the suggestions I could find involve reinstalling the Flash Player, but that seems to be impossible right now after it was discontinued. Is there any way I can still get the particular files I need to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the answer here:

[Reddit - How to use apps that rely on ActiveX in 2021?](https://www.reddit.com/r/flash/comments/lwf0mm/how_to_use_apps_that_rely_on_activex_in_2021/)

Option 1: 
Seems like installing in **Windows 7 compatibility mode** is enough.
Download the Flash Player installer here:
 https://archive.org/download/flashplayerarchivedversions2/357/fp_32.0.0.344_archive.zip

Option 2: 
Follow the **12 steps** process shown in [this main post](https://www.reddit.com/r/flash/comments/lwf0mm/how_to_use_apps_that_rely_on_activex_in_2021/gpobsx8/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)...